# Can you format an eigen sparse matrix?

Tags: c++, math, io, eigen

I have some pretty large matrices that are extremely sparse (7 non zeros among 300 for each row).

I need to print the matrix to a file following a specific format.

I tried:

```
Eigen::IOFormat HeavyFmt(Eigen::FullPrecision, 0, " ", ";\n", "", "", "[", "]");
    std::cout << bijection.format(HeavyFmt) << std::endl;
```

But the compiler complains that:

```
error: ‘class Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int>’ has no member named ‘format’
  292 |     std::cout << bijection.format(HeavyFmt) << std::endl;
```

So what can I do? Is there a sparse version of the format command?

Comment: Do you want to print it as-if it was a dense matrix? Or something like MatrixGarden format?

Comment: I want to print it as a matlab .m file

Comment: The easiest solution would be to temporarily convert your matrix to a dense matrix: `Eigen::MatrixXf(bijection).format(HeavyFmt)`. That does not scale well, if your matrix is really large -- but then printing it as text would not be a good idea either.

Comment: @Makogan I'm a bit rusty with Matlab, but isn't a .m file a matlab script? Don't you want a .mat file (which would be binary)? What Matlab function do you need to use for reading? While we are at it, if you just need *some* form of matlab compatibility, consider switching to HDF5. Matlab can read it and it works reasonably well with sparse data if you enable compression and do a bit of extra work.